# What happens in this code block during php oop?

Tags: php, oop, type-hinting

Could someone please explain the third line where Request and $request is used. It would be great if you could provide me a link having an explanation of the same? I just want to know what is happening there.

```
    <?php
       class xyz {
        public function foo(Request $request){
          //some code
        }
       }
```

Comment: where did you get the code from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type hinting:

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

```
<?php
// An example class
class MyClass
{
    /**
     * A test function
     *
     * First parameter must be an object of type OtherClass
     */
    public function test(OtherClass $otherclass) {
        echo $otherclass->var;
    }


    /**
     * Another test function
     *
     * First parameter must be an array
     */
    public function test_array(array $input_array) {
        print_r($input_array);
    }
}

// Another example class
class OtherClass {
    public $var = 'Hello World';
}
```

It throws an error if the argument is not of the type specified:

```
<?php
// An instance of each class
$myclass = new MyClass;
$otherclass = new OtherClass;

// Fatal Error: Argument 1 must be an object of class OtherClass
$myclass->test('hello');

// Fatal Error: Argument 1 must be an instance of OtherClass
$foo = new stdClass;
$myclass->test($foo);

// Fatal Error: Argument 1 must not be null
$myclass->test(null);

// Works: Prints Hello World
$myclass->test($otherclass);

// Fatal Error: Argument 1 must be an array
$myclass->test_array('a string');

// Works: Prints the array
$myclass->test_array(array('a', 'b', 'c'));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Arguments:

- http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Type hints:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Answer (score 0):

An Object of the type `Request` is being passed to function `foo`.

It is made available to the function `foo` in a private variable named `$request`.

Answer (score 0):

The third line defines a class method called foo that can get a `$request` argument of type "Request".

This is a security measure for the class developer. Determine that

```
<?php
    class User
    {
        private $username;

        public function get_username()
        {
            return $this->username;
        }
    }

    class xyz()
    {
        public function foo(User $currentUser)
        {
            $currentUser->get_username();
        }
    }

    $x = new xyz();

    $u = new User();
    $x->foo($u);           // That will not produce any error because we pass an Object argument of type User

    $name = "my_name";
    $x->foo($name);        // This will produce an error because we pass a wrong type of argument
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [type hint](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php), to tell php to expect an object wich has

```
$request instanceof Request == true
```

Please note that this will actually **not** ensure anything. If $request is null or another object, there will most likely only a *catchable fatal error* be thrown, and so you have to test for a valid value anyway.